# set focus in next html input after editing and clicking enter

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 inputs in html form.

I wrote html and copied js from another topic here. But I can't understand, what I need write down for working.

For example, I need after inserting data in input with id "tLogin" and clicking Enter moving focus on next input with id "tTable", and next move focus to input with id "tOrder". After entering data to tOrder return focus to tLogin.

```js
function keyPressFunction(e) {    
    const focus = $(document.activeElement); //get your active elememt ie select input
    let inputView;
    if (e.which === 13 || e.keyCode === 13 ) {
      inputView = focus.closest('div').next().find(".field-focus"); // go to tbody and search for next class name .field-focus
    }
    inputView.show().focus(); //focus and show next input in table
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>CLR: PACKING</title>
<meta charset = "UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
       integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
            
    <?!= include("index-css"); ?>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="conteiner">
        <form novalidate>
                <h6 class="title">PACKING</h6>
            <div class="dws-input">
                <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                <div>
                    <div class="form-floating mb-3 mt-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" novalidate id="tLogin" name= "username" placeholder= "Логин:" autofocus > 
                        <label for="tLogin">Login:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-floating mb-3 mt-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control"  novalidate id="tTable" name= "text" placeholder= "Номер стола:" >
                        <label for="tTable">Table:</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-floating mb-3 mt-3">
                    <input type="text"  novalidate class="form-control" id="tOrder" name= "text" placeholder= "Заказ:" >
                    <label for="tOrder">Order:</label>
                </div> 
            </div>  
        </form>
    </div>

</body>



</html>
```

Thank you for help!

Comment: Hi, the `Enter` keypress is usually used to trigger `click` or `tap` actions. The recommended way to navigate between different form elements or any HTML elements via keyboard is to use the `TAB` key.

Comment: @Nitin thank you, I know this, but my situation a little different. the html will load on the display of scanner and the scanning barcode is like clicking Enter and focus must automatically go away to next input after this.

Comment: Ah okay, got it. Thanks for clarification :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Nitin mentions in the comment above, the `Enter` key is mainly used as a button press or submitting the form. Anyway, try this example for your solution.

```js
const inputs = document.querySelector('.dws-input');
const formControl = document.querySelectorAll('.form-control');

formControl[0].focus();

function keyPressFunction(ev) {
  if (ev.code !== 'Enter') return;
  if (ev.target.value === '') return;

  for (const i of formControl) {
    if (i.value === '') {
      i.nextElementSibling.focus();
      break;
    }
  }
}

inputs.addEventListener('keydown', keyPressFunction);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div class="conteiner">
  <form novalidate>
    <h6 class="title">PACKING</h6>
    <div class="dws-input">
      <div class="col-md-3"></div>
      <div>
        <div class="form-floating mb-3 mt-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" novalidate id="tLogin" name="username" placeholder="Логин:" autofocus />
          <label for="tLogin">Login:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating mb-3 mt-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" novalidate id="tTable" name="text" placeholder="Номер стола:" />
          <label for="tTable">Table:</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-floating mb-3 mt-3">
        <input type="text" novalidate class="form-control" id="tOrder" name="text" placeholder="Заказ:" />
        <label for="tOrder">Order:</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much for help! I think your way is very helpful!

Comment: I will try near time and close this this question)

Answer (score 1):

Please use this code.

```
const ids = $(":input").toArray().map(val => val.id);
$(":input").keypress(function keyPressFunction(e) {
    const nextId = (ids.indexOf(document.activeElement.id) + 1) % ids.length;
    if (e.which === 13 || e.keyCode === 13 ) {
        document.getElementById(ids[nextId]).focus();
    }
    
});
```

Comment: thank you. I 'm junior with jQuery. Can you help me by js?))